# Let $ \ a_{j+1}=\min \{q \in \mathbb{N} : \frac{1}{q} \leq \frac{a}{b}-\frac{1}{a_1}- \cdots -\frac{1}{a_j} \} $, show that $a_{j+1}>a_j$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $ \ a_{j+1}=\min \{q \in \mathbb{N} : \frac{1}{q} \leq \frac{a}{b}-\frac{1}{a_1}- \cdots -\frac{1}{a_j} \}$ and  $\frac{a}{b}-\frac{1}{a_1}- \cdots -\frac{1}{a_j}$, and $a<b$, show that

$a_{j+1}>a_j$

**Answer:**

Since $ \ a_{j+1}=\min \{q \in \mathbb{N} : \frac{1}{q} \leq \frac{a}{b}-\frac{1}{a_1}- \cdots -\frac{1}{a_j} \} $ , we have

$a_1= \min \{q \in \mathbb{N}: \frac{1}{q} \leq \frac{a}{b} \} $

$a_2=\min \{q \in \mathbb{N}: \frac{1}{q} \leq \frac{a}{b}-\frac{1}{a_1} \} $

But how to conclude the proof.

we have the identity $ 0 \leq aa_1-b<a $ also in our hand.

Comment: You can use the inequality $$\frac{2}{x}\geq \frac{1}{x-1}$$ for all integers $x>1$.

Answer (score 0):

$\ a_{j+1}=\inf \{q \in \mathbb{N} : \frac{1}{q} \leq \frac{a}{b}-\frac{1}{a_1}- \cdots -\frac{1}{a_j} \}$, 
$\ a_{j}=\inf\{q \in \mathbb{N} : \frac{1}{q} \leq \frac{a}{b}-\frac{1}{a_1}- \cdots -\frac{1}{a_{j-1}} \}$. Now let $A=\{q \in \mathbb{N} : \frac{1}{q} \leq \frac{a}{b}-\frac{1}{a_1}- \cdots -\frac{1}{a_{j-1}} \}$ and $B=\{q \in \mathbb{N} : \frac{1}{q} \leq \frac{a}{b}-\frac{1}{a_1}- \cdots -\frac{1}{a_{j}} \}$. Then $B\subset A\implies inf(A)<inf(B)\implies a_j<a_{j+1}$.

Comment: $min(A)$ for a set $A$ is valid when $A$ is a finite set. In case $A$ is infinite the notation sould be $inf(A)$